# Is it possible to scroll ListView to a listrow's child element?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView with quite "high" rows. The rows have quite complex layouts, and I'd like to get ListView to scroll to exactly a child element of a row. Is this possible?

I've only found .smoothScollToPosition(), but I can only specify a whole row in that. I need something more precise, to e.g. scroll to a child element in the middle of a row.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the ListView method [smoothScrollToPositionFromTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPositionFromTop%28int,%20int,%20int%29) (inherited from AbsListView)

> Smoothly scroll to the specified
>   adapter position. The view will scroll
>   such that the indicated position is
>   displayed offset pixels from the top
>   edge of the view. If this is
>   impossible, (e.g. the offset would
>   scroll the first or last item beyond
>   the boundaries of the list) it will
>   get as close as possible. The scroll
>   will take duration milliseconds to
>   complete.

You'll be responsible for calculating the offset required to land in the middle of a row - that is beyond the scope of your question as it stands.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it to work with this one. It's a bit tricky to get the exact height in pixels for the correct offset, but it works .