# Programmatically scroll to a specific position in an Android ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

How can I programmatically scroll to a specific position in a `ListView`?

For example, I have a `String[] {A,B,C,D....}`, and I need to set the top visible item of the `ListView` to the index 21 of my `String[]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to scroll ListView to a listrow's child element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626988/is-it-possible-to-scroll-listview-to-a-listrows-child-element)

Comment: see my answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/29345217/1881527

Answer (score 403):

For a direct scroll:

```
getListView().setSelection(21);
```

For a smooth scroll:

```
getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(21);
```

Comment: Cool, this is exactly what I want!

Comment: Another difference: the first one tries to set in the middle of list.

Comment: @Steve "Smoothly scroll to the specified adapter position. The view will scroll such that the indicated position is displayed." http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition(int)

Comment: @HandlerExploit thankyou very much for your concern, i will try it and will let you know...

Comment: `smoothScrollToPosition` is not working, any suggestion ?

Comment: @SweetWisherツ try to post delay the execution, something like: `listView.post(() -> listView.smoothScrollToPosition());`

Answer (score 65):

## For a SmoothScroll with Scroll duration:

`getListView().smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position,offset,duration);`

> Parameters
> position -> Position to scroll to
> offset   ---->Desired distance in pixels of position from the top of the view when scrolling is finished
> duration-> Number of milliseconds to use for the scroll

**Note:** From API 11.

HandlerExploit's answer was what I was looking for, but My listview is quite lengthy and also with alphabet scroller. Then I found that the same function can take other parameters as well :)

---

**Edit:**(From AFDs suggestion)

To position the current selection:

```
int h1 = mListView.getHeight();
int h2 = listViewRow.getHeight();

mListView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position, h1/2 - h2/2, duration);
```

Comment: Works fine. To improve your answer, the offset can be calculated as described on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540223/center-a-listview-on-its-current-selection

Comment: what is v.getHeight()?

Comment: @Panache v is the listview's row

Answer (score 10):

Put your code in handler as follows,

```
public void timerDelayRunForScroll(long time) {
        Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {           
            public void run() {   
                try {
                    lstView.smoothScrollToPosition(YOUR_POSITION);
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }, time); 
    }
```

and then call this method like,

```
timerDelayRunForScroll(100);
```

CHEERS!!!

Answer (score 8):

The `Listview` scroll will be positioned to top by default, but want to scroll if not visible then use this:

```
if (listView1.getFirstVisiblePosition() > position || listView1.getLastVisiblePosition() < position)
            listView1.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: Thanks @zalak  Solve my issue , Give you up

Answer (score 7):

I have set OnGroupExpandListener and override onGroupExpand() as:

and use setSelectionFromTop() method which
Sets the selected item and positions the selection y pixels from the top edge of the ListView. (If in touch mode, the item will not be selected but it will still be positioned appropriately.) (android docs)

```
    yourlist.setOnGroupExpandListener (new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

            expList.setSelectionFromTop(groupPosition, 0);
            //your other code
        }
    });
```

Comment: I need to scroll another view simultaneously while scrolling lisview. Using setSelectionFromTop on listview for scrolling blocks the UI thread which makes the scrolling of another view slow. Can you  give some suggestion how to do it?

Answer (score 5):

> Handling listView scrolling using UP/ Down using.button

If someone is interested in handling listView one row up/down using button. then.

```
public View.OnClickListener onChk = new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {

                 int index = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                 getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(index+1); // For increment. 

}
});
```

Comment: I give you the up vote just because you are the only one that showed a way to get the current position, but you should improve example.

Answer (score 5):

If someone looking for a similar functionality like Gmail app,

The Listview scroll will be positioned to top by default. Thanks for the hint. 
amalBit.
Just subtract it. That's it.

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int h1 = mDrawerList.getHeight();
            int h2 = header.getHeight();
            mDrawerList.smoothScrollToPosition(h2-h1);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to jump directly to the desired position in a listView just use

**listView.setSelection(int position);**

and if you want to jump smoothly to the desired position in listView just use

**listView.smoothScrollToPosition(int position);**

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me. Combination of answers by amalBit & Melbourne Lopes

```
public void timerDelayRunForScroll(long time) {
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {           
        public void run() {   
            try {
                  int h1 = mListView.getHeight();
                  int h2 = v.getHeight();

                  mListView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(YOUR_POSITION, h1/2 - h2/2, 500);  

            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }, time); 
}
```

and then call this method like:

```
timerDelayRunForScroll(400);
```

Answer (score 2):

it is easy
`list-view.set selection(you pos);`
or you can save your position with `SharedPreference` and when you start activity
it get preferences and `setSeletion` to that int

Comment: all i wanted to do was automatically move to the top of the list, without any scrolling animation...this worked perfectly for that

Answer (score 2):

-If you just want the list to scroll up\dawn to a specific position:

```
myListView.smoothScrollToPosition(i);
```

-if you want to get the position of a specific item in myListView:

```
myListView.getItemAtPosition(i);
```

-also this `myListView.getVerticalScrollbarPosition(i);`can helps you.

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 2):

You need two things to precisely define the scroll position of a listView:

To get the current listView Scroll position:

```
int firstVisiblePosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); 
int topEdge=listView.getChildAt(0).getTop(); //This gives how much the top view has been scrolled.
```

To set the listView Scroll position:

```
listView.setSelectionFromTop(firstVisiblePosition,0);
// Note the '-' sign for scrollTo.. 
listView.scrollTo(0,-topEdge);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution to allow the scroll up and down using two different buttons.

As suggested by @Nepster I implement the scroll programmatically using the  getFirstVisiblePosition() and getLastVisiblePosition() to get the current position.

```
final ListView lwresult = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rds_rdi_mat_list);
    .....

        if (list.size() > 0) {
            ImageButton bnt = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.down_action);
            bnt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bnt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(lwresult.getLastVisiblePosition()<lwresult.getAdapter().getCount()){
                        lwresult.smoothScrollToPosition(lwresult.getLastVisiblePosition()+5);
                    }else{
                        lwresult.smoothScrollToPosition(lwresult.getAdapter().getCount());

                    }
                }
            });
            bnt = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.up_action);
            bnt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            bnt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(lwresult.getFirstVisiblePosition()>0){
                        lwresult.smoothScrollToPosition(lwresult.getFirstVisiblePosition()-5);
                    }else{
                        lwresult.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
```