# Android - how to move the scrollbar in a listView

Tags: android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [programmatically Scroll to a specific position in Android ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561353/programmatically-scroll-to-a-specific-position-in-android-listview)

I have a listview with a scrollbar.  I want to shift the scrollbar down a few pixels.

```
android:scrollY="20dp"
```

I tried setting this in my listView but nothing changes.

Any ideas on how to achieve the offset?

Comment: Nope, I don't want to programatically scroll, I want to move the entire bar down

Comment: @AleksG: I am not sure the two questions are related. I think the OP wants to move the position of scrollbar in the `ListView` down a few pixels and not the scroll to an item in the `ListView`. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Yeah @SiddharthLele you are correct :)

Answer (score 1):

you can set it on the code behind with setSelectionFromTop

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelectionFromTop(int, int)

I think scrollY is more for scroll view.. I have not tried it on list view from the looks of it I don't think it works in a listview.

I don't think you can scroll from the xml as well if you see the documentation listview xml non inherited attributes are only the following:

android:divider
android:dividerHeight
android:entries
android:footerDividersEnabled
android:headerDividersEnabled

I checked AbsListView they don't have attributes that allows you to do that either..

Answer (score 0):

For this problem You should create a custom scroll bar with the following code.

```
    <layer-list  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:top="15dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >                    
                <solid android:color="#421700"/>                     
            </shape>                
        </item>           
    </layer-list>
```

set it to the view using attribute

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical
```