# Android ListView with edittext in items

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have a `ListView` where every item has an `EditText`, when I focus on the last items the soft keyboard appears, but the `EditText` does not so it stays in the bottom of the screen, what can I do ?

I have this in my manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to make the listview scroll to the clicked EditText, so (I guess) it will be displayed in the visible part of the screen.
As in this question [Programmatically scroll to a specific position in an Android ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561353/programmatically-scroll-to-a-specific-position-in-an-android-listview), you should identify which item has been clicked and then scroll to it.

Comment: I believe if the item is in the very bottom, there is no more room for scrolling it there ?

Comment: I don't know exactly what happens, but I think you're right, if there's no room it can't scroll there.
See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295672/android-soft-keyboard-covers-edittext-field) and also [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html), maybe the answer is to use _extract mode_.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Adapter's `getLastVisiblePostition`:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getLastVisiblePosition()

Then on the click of `EditText`, `setSelection` for the `ListView`(depending on the height of soft keyboard and each item row of the `ListView`);
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setSelection(int)