# how to scroll listview to specific position in android programmatically

Tags: android, android-listview

I try to make listview to scroll to position , i have tried all possible functions but all not work

for more explanation of code
firstly : i put markers on map then call list adapter
secondly L if user click marker on map the list view should show the selected position as marker clicked

```
private void Putting_places_on_Map(final List<PlaceModel> Places) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (int i = 0; i < Places.size(); i++) {
        LatLng place_loc = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(Places.get(i)
                .getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(Places.get(i)
                .getLongitude()));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place_loc).icon(
                BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.glossygreencirclemarker)));
    }

    // when marker clicked
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LatLng PlaceLocation = marker.getPosition();
            int selected_marker=-1;
            for (int i = 0; i < Places.size(); i++) {
                if (PlaceLocation.latitude == Double.parseDouble(Places
                        .get(i).getLatitude())
                        && PlaceLocation.longitude == Double
                                  .parseDouble(Places.get(i).getLongitude())) {
                    selected_marker=i;
                }
            }
            Update_List_Places(Places, selected_marker);
            return false;
        }
    });

}
private void Update_List_Places(List<PlaceModel> Places,
        int selected_marker_position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    list_places_returned = true;
    ListPlacesNearbyAdapter placesNearbyAdapter = new ListPlacesNearbyAdapter(
            (ArrayList<PlaceModel>) Places, activity,
            selected_marker_position);
    placesNearbyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    if(selected_marker_position != -1){

        //listview_nearby_locations.setSelection(selected_marker_position);
        //listview_nearby_locations.smoothScrollToPosition(selected_marker_position);
        //listview_nearby_locations.setSelectionFromTop(selected_marker_position, 100);
        int y= selected_marker_position*40;
        listview_nearby_locations.scrollTo(0,y);
    }
    listview_nearby_locations.setAdapter(placesNearbyAdapter);
}
```

see this pic
[image]

Comment: `smoothScrollToPosition`

Comment: You can use setSelection() method

Comment: Already i used it but not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
listview_nearby_locations.setSelection(9);
```

Answer (score 2):

For a direct scroll:

```
getListView().setSelection(21);
```

For a smooth scroll:

```
getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(21);
```

Taken from here: [Programmatically scroll to a specific position in an Android ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561353/programmatically-scroll-to-a-specific-position-in-an-android-listview)

Comment: getlistview() not defined in my class

Answer (score 2):

thanks guys i used this

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(selected_marker_position != -1){                 
                listview_nearby_locations.setSelection(selected_marker_position);
            }
        }
    };
    runnable.run();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code..

```
context.yourListView.smoothScrollToPosition(10);
```

Comment: Can you provide some more explanation?