# Want Scrolling list to specific position

Tags: android

Can We scroll listview on basis of item name on button clicking in android.
Like I have list with multiple header and i want to scroll the list to that header on button clicking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to scroll listview to specific position in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191413/how-to-scroll-listview-to-specific-position-in-android-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

You can get list position by name using below function.

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof YourModel)) return false;
        YourModel that = (YourModel) o;
        return Objects.equals(itemName, that.itemName);
    }
```

After that you can scroll to particular position using scrollToPosition(position);

Comment: can you please explain this metho

Comment: is it possible that i can set some value of list's items and scroll the list to that value like i have three button and want to scroll list to specific value set by on each button click

Comment: This is method is for get list position by value. Suppose, you have list with id, name.
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "abc"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "XYZ"
  }
]

Now, you can get "XYZ" position using this function.

@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof YourModel)) return false;
        YourModel that = (YourModel) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, that.name);
    }
yourList.get("XYZ") => get list position of "XYZ" value.

Answer (score 0):

**For scroll to any postition X:**

```
getListView().setSelection(X);
```

**Smoothly scroll to the specified adapter position.**

```
smoothScrollToPosition(int position)
```

Comment: guys my code dont know the position  only know name of item. s

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `Recyclerview` then try this

```
yourRecyclerview.scrollToPosition(position);
```

And if you are using `ListView` then try this

```
// For smooth scroll:
getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(position);

//For direct scroll
getListView().setSelection(position);
```