# How to scroll a few pixels down programatically Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, scroll

I made a Ctrl+F search box with next ocurrence button, when i click next it scroll to next word, but the word is out of screen , if i scroll a few pixels down , you are able to see it.

so after the method find next is called i would like to scroll a little more so the highlighted word is visible.

```
mFindNextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.find_next);
    mFindNextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mCurrentWebView.findNext(true);
            //scroll a little more()
        }
    });
```

Comment: This could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561353/programmatically-scroll-to-a-specific-position-in-an-android-listview If not, provide more informations.

Comment: i need to scroll from the current position , y pixels down

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollView.getScrollY()+10); // Scroll down 10 more pixels
```