# How can I set the initial scroll position of my list?

Tags: android

I set my adapter to my list

```
ListView listView = (ListView)  view.findViewById(R.id.listViewMovies);
listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Now how can I set the initial scroll position of my list?

**edit**

`smoothScrollToPosition` does not work

```
ListView listView = (ListView)  view.findViewById(R.id.listViewMovies);
listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
listView.smoothScrollToPosition(123);
```

`setSelection` does not work

```
ListView listView = (ListView)  view.findViewById(R.id.listViewMovies);
listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
listView.setSelection(123);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calling

```
listview.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        listview.setSelection(mSelectedPosition);
    }
});
```

seems to have helped others.

Comment: What do I do with this code? Just copy paste and it is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `listview.smoothScrollToPosition()` function.
refer this :
[Programmatically scroll to a specific position in an Android ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561353/programmatically-scroll-to-a-specific-position-in-an-android-listview)

Comment: use the code in onResume method of the activity or fragment. also you may try, listview.setSelection()

Comment: in onCreate declare the listview, set its adapter, but call the smoothScrollToPosition method in onResume, try this once, if not already