# How to scroll to a specific list position inside AlertDialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I can successfully display an alert dialog with a list.
What I'm trying to achieve is to scroll to a specific position of this list. Is there a way to do this?
Below there is the code

```
fun createAlert(activity: Activity, mandatory: Boolean, provinceSelected: (Int) -> Unit) {
        val provinceDialog: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        provinceDialog.setTitle(activity.getString(R.string.select_province_from_list))
        provinceDialog.setCancelable(!mandatory)
        val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, R.layout.province_list_row_item, SubAdministrativeAreas.provincesList)
        provinceDialog.setAdapter(arrayAdapter
        ) { _, positionSelected ->
            provinceSelected(positionSelected)
        }
        
        
        /**
         * Here I should move to an adapter position
         */
        
        
        provinceDialog.show()
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AlertDialog` to get the list and after show you can scroll to a certain position.

Try this way it should work .

```
fun createAlert(activity: Activity, mandatory: Boolean, provinceSelected: (Int) -> Unit) {
    val provinceDialog: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
    provinceDialog.setTitle(activity.getString(R.string.select_province_from_list))
    provinceDialog.setCancelable(!mandatory)
    val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, R.layout.province_list_row_item, SubAdministrativeAreas.provincesList)
    provinceDialog.setAdapter(arrayAdapter
    ) { _, positionSelected ->
        provinceSelected(positionSelected)
    }
    val dialog = provinceDialog.create()
    dialog.setOnShowListener {
            dialog.listView.smoothScrollToPosition(11)
    }
    dialog.show()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the `ListView` an `AlertDialog` uses via [`AlertDialog.getListView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog#getListView()).

There are then a few easy ways to scroll the list programmatically, this post seems to cover it - [Programmatically scroll to a specific position in an Android ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561353/programmatically-scroll-to-a-specific-position-in-an-android-listview/22242885).